# How can I use a var to provide multiple arguments to a function?

Tags: arguments, apply

Here is a simple example in which I would like to replace

```el
(start-process "ls" "*temp*" "ls" "-l" "-a" "-t" "-r") ; this works
```

with

```el
(setq some-var ????) ; <-- Need to figure this part out
(start-process "ls" "*temp*" "ls" some-var)
```

But I cannot figure out how to represent that `some-var`.

Below did not work:

```el
;; Attempt 1
(setq some-var "-l -a -t -r")

;; Attempt 2
(setq some-var '("-l" "-a" "-t" "-r"))
```

I basically need a solution to be able to provide variable number of args (`&rest args`) to a function using a variable.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361819/how-to-give-a-list-as-arguments-to-a-function-in-elisp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the function `apply`. Use it as follows:

```el
(setq some-var '("-l" "-a" "-t" "-r"))
(apply #'start-process "ls" "*temp*" "ls" some-var)
```

Comment: @PythonNut You don't need `function` as long as the byte-compiler does not complain. `start-process` is used as symbol here. There is nothing the byte-compiler can optimize. Otherwise `function` would also be used there: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html#Calling-Functions. `function` is useful for `lambda`-expressions and other evaluable lisp expressions.

Comment: @Tobias I tend to think of the sharp quote as being an annotation for the reader as well, just so it's extra clear that `start-process` is intended to be interpreted as a function. With that in mind, I tend to sharp-quote all symbols referencing functions for consistency.